# Saving checked fields, like in Online Shop

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, model-view-controller, http-post

I am trying to do something like checkout. In online Shops. I am getting list from Data base and I want to send selected ones to other view.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <fieldset>
            <div class="clstable">
                <table id="table" border="0" style="width:60%">
                  <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                        {
                            <tr>                            
                                <td name="Sub">@item.Name</td>                           
                                <td>
                                    <input name="Nam" type="number" min="0" width="10" />
                                </td>
                                <td align="center"><input name="Check" type="checkbox" padding-left 5px; /></td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
               <button type="submit" aligh="center">Submit/Buy</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>

 public class DBData
    {            
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Subscription { get; set; }
    }

[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult About()
        {
            var subscriptions = new List<DBData>();
            using (var db = new OnePortalVsEntities())
            {
              ...
            }
            return View(subscriptions);
        }
```

how do I get selected Subs and number (selected in Input number) of them to other View?
Should I create a Session or post all to controller somehow?

Comment: look at editorfor instead of input  - then after post You will have it in model

Comment: You need to show your model. You current implementation is just creating inputs and checkboxes with duplicate `name` attributes (without indexers) so have no relationship at all to your model when you submit the form.

Comment: At the very least your model (view model) needs (say) `bool IsSelected` and `int Number` properties. Then you need a `for` loop in the view - `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].Number) @Html.CheckboxFor(m => m[i].IsSelected) ..... }` so that you bind your form controls to your model

Comment: Tnx all resolved the issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <fieldset>
        <div class="clstable">
            <table id="table" border="0" style="width:60%">
                <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++ )
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td name="Sub">@Model[i].Name</td>
                        <td>
                            <input name="Nam" type="number" min="0" width="10" />
                        </td>
                        <td align="center">@Html.CheckBoxFor(x=>x[i].BoolProperty)</td>
                    </tr>
                }
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <button type="submit" aligh="center">Submit/Buy</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}
```

You missed also `<tbody>` tag.